# Update record in rails index view with timestamp on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get rails to update a record on click by entering a timestamp on the record. I am totally new to this concept and have checked other tutorials but don't know where to go from here if I could get some help I'd really appreciate it.

User sees list of clients

The column with the email, phone, etc when clicked updates the Contacted table's 'date' column with the current date timestamp.

My plan is for the record to disseapear so that a user doesn't over contact a client. I hope this makes sense.

Evan

Comment: Before i can help you, I need to understand your scenario, 1- clicking mail or phone should update index table timestamp to the current record's timestamp? 2- clicking mail or phone should update record timestamps and index table timestamps as well ? Which scenario you mean 1 or 2 ?

Comment: @amirEl-bashary Thank you for your reply, very grateful. Option 2 is my desired goal

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, I'll pick the easiest one, which does not implement AJAX, so that the point can be clear

Of course using Ajax would be better but let's start

Assuming the client model called `Client`, and the timestamp to be updated is `updated_at`

on you routes you should have something like:

`resources :clients`

change it to:

```rb
resources :clients do
  member do
    post :update_timestamps
  end
end
```

check `bundle exec rake routes` to check the right path name which should be `update_timestamps_client_path(pass_client_object_here)`

on your table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= @clients.each do |client| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to client.name, update_timestamps_client_path(client), method: :post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to client.phone, update_timestamps_client_path(client), method: :post %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now to the `clients_controller.rb`, you should have something similar to this structure -Of course never the same :)-

```rb
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @client = Client.all
  end

  # Let's define the update timestamps method
  def update_timestamps
    @client = Client.find(params[:id]
    # We don't need to add any conditions in case of failure since it's almost impossible for this method to fail
    @client.update(updated_at: Time.zone.now)
  end
end
```

Ok so.. Now when you click the client name or phone, it's record should be updated without reloading the page

Something missing ?
Of course, we still need to hide this record as you said, and we can do this very easy with `jQuery`

Please excuse my bad approach on jQuery since i'm not that good with front-end after all, i can survive only :D

I hope someone can write a better jQuery code as a comment, using class instead of ID and also use `$(this)` so the jQuery code can be a lot more cleaner

on the bottom of the page or on the corresponding assets javascript file add this code

```js
 function hide(id) {          
  $('#client_' + id).toggle();
}
```

and modify the table rows to be like this

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= @clients.each do |client| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to client.name, update_timestamps_client_path(client), method: :post, id: "client_#{client.id}", onclick: "hide(#{client.id});" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to client.phone, update_timestamps_client_path(client), method: :post, id: "client_#{client.id}", onclick: "hide(#{client.id});" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now when you click any of the name of the phone, the updated_at will be updated with the current time and the record will disappear just for the current refresh!

Let's say you want to prevent it from appearing if the updated_at is the same day ?
then you'll need to skip with with `next` when listing them or when you query them

The easier now is using `next` as following on the `index.html.erb`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= @clients.each do |client| %>
      # This is to skip listing the clients which was updated today
      <% next if client.updated_at.today? %>

      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to client.name, update_timestamps_client_path(client), method: :post, id: "client_#{client.id}", onclick: "hide(#{client.id});" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to client.phone, update_timestamps_client_path(client), method: :post, id: "client_#{client.id}", onclick: "hide(#{client.id});" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You don't have the follow this exactly as it's written, i'm just delivering you a concept, you can do it in a much better way, and don't forget to refactor the code the applying it, i just made it as clear as i could, hopefully it helps you :)

Let me know if anything stands on your way :)

Comment: thank you for an elaborate response, I will take some time today to try it out. Thanks again. Evan

Comment: I think as my contacted is a seperate controller, iwth each time contacted as a seperate entry, is there a way to update this other controller with a new entry for the client? Thanks again for your consideration

Comment: Of course there is a way but i need am example of your controller so i can understand your point clearly, as i'm still confused a little, didn't get the full point of your last comment, and you're welcome :)

Comment: apologies for the delay, I just got married. For the controller, my records show up on one controller called Clients. When I enter a record when they contact me those go into 'Contacted' which is another. How do I enter a row with the client_id and 'method' of contact when someone clicks on the telephone button on the Client index page?

Comment: Congratulations, And i just got married last friday as well :), I'll try to post an answer for your question ASAP :)

Comment: congratulations to you too! Looking forward to your response!

Comment: any thoughts on this?